# How to fix the Base64 Errors I am getting?

Tags: java, base64

After reading a lot about AES, JCE and its unlimited strength policy files for 256 bit key, and this [Oracle/Sun guide](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Security/AES/AES_v1.html) I've implemented this.

**UPDATE**

I combined the code provided by sun and made a java class
AESencrp.java

```
/**
 *
 * @author MUDASSIR
 */

import java.security.*;
import javax.crypto.*;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import sun.misc.*;

public class AESencrp {

     private static final String ALGO = "AES";
//    private static final byte[] keyValue = 
//        new byte[] { 'T', 'h', 'e', 'B', 'e', 's', 't',
//'S', 'e', 'c', 'r','e', 't', 'K', 'e', 'y' };

public static String encrypt(String Data, byte[] keyValue) throws Exception {
        Key key = generateKey(keyValue);
        Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance(ALGO);
        c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
        byte[] encVal = c.doFinal(Data.getBytes());
        String encryptedValue = new BASE64Encoder().encode(encVal);
        return encryptedValue;
    }

    public static String decrypt(String encryptedData, byte[] keyValue) throws Exception {
        Key key = generateKey(keyValue);
        Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance(ALGO);
        c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
        byte[] decodedValue = new BASE64Decoder().decodeBuffer(encryptedData);
        byte[] decValue = c.doFinal(decodedValue);
        String decryptedValue = new String(decValue);
        return decryptedValue;
    }
    private static Key generateKey(byte[] keyValue) throws Exception {
        Key key = new SecretKeySpec(keyValue, ALGO);
        return key;
}

}
```

This works just fine, but whenever i build my project it give the warning that 
"Base64encoder is a proprietary software and must be removed in the future release".

When i removed the base64 encoder and used the asHex method instead(as provided by the sun guide [here](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Security/AES/AES_v1.html)), it gave me a BadPadding exception.
Exception in thread "main" javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded

This is my code without base64 encoder

```
/**
 *
 * @author MUDASSIR
 */

import java.security.*;
import javax.crypto.*;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import sun.misc.*;

public class AESencrp2 {

     private static final String ALGO = "AES";
//    private static final byte[] keyValue = 
//        new byte[] { 'T', 'h', 'e', 'B', 'e', 's', 't',
//'S', 'e', 'c', 'r','e', 't', 'K', 'e', 'y' };

     public static String asHex(byte buf[]) {
        StringBuilder strbuf = new StringBuilder(buf.length * 2);
        int i;

        for (i = 0; i < buf.length; i++) {
            if (((int) buf[i] & 0xff) < 0x10) {
                strbuf.append("0");
            }

            strbuf.append(Long.toString((int) buf[i] & 0xff, 16));
        }

        return strbuf.toString();
    }

public static String encrypt(String Data, byte[] keyValue) throws Exception {
        Key key = generateKey(keyValue);
        Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance(ALGO);
        c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
        byte[] encryptedValue = c.doFinal(Data.getBytes());
        return asHex(encryptedValue);
    }

    public static String decrypt(String encryptedData, byte[] keyValue) throws Exception {
        Key key = generateKey(keyValue);
        Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance(ALGO);
        c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
        byte[] decValue = c.doFinal(encryptedData.getBytes());
        String decryptedValue = new String(decValue);
        return decryptedValue;
    }
    private static Key generateKey(byte[] keyValue) throws Exception {
        Key key = new SecretKeySpec(keyValue, ALGO);
        return key;
}

}
```

This is the main, where i try the code

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

        byte[] keyValue = new byte[] { 'T', 'h', 'e', 'B', 'e', 's', 't',
'S', 'e', 'c', 'r','e', 't', 'K', 'e', 'y' };

        String password = "This is the data that is going to be encrypted";

        String passwordEnc = AESencrp.encrypt(password, keyValue);
        //String passwordEnc = AESencrp2.encrypt(password, keyValue);

        String passwordDec = AESencrp.decrypt(passwordEnc, keyValue);
        //String passwordDec = AESencrp.decrypt(passwordEnc, keyValue);

        System.out.println("Plain Text : " + password);
        System.out.println("Encrypted Text : " + passwordEnc);
        System.out.println("Decrypted Text : " + passwordDec);
}
```

Problem,

1. 1 - If i use base64 encoder, its proprietary.
2. 2 - If is use asHex method provided by sun, i get bad padding exception.

Help please.

Comment: What exactly is you question? How to enrypt data using AES? Or how to run sources you provided? Or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use your own Base64 encoding/decoding routine to fix the problem.

Comment: what do you mean my own encoding/decoding routine ??

Comment: That you use or code a Base64 encoder/decoder. For example, Apache Commons has one.

Comment: I imported this import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
and tried new Base64().encode(--byte--); 
But it's not working

Comment: See https://commons.apache.org/codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.html for class documentation.

Comment: Ok org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64 solved the problem :) thanks for the help everyone of you...